# Change ion-view background color

Tags: javascript, css, ionic-framework

I am using ionic, I have created my main title using ion-view

```
<ion-view title="test" class="frame_look_feel"> <ion-nav-buttons
    side="left">
<button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons> <ion-content class="has-header">
<h1>Search</h1>
</ion-content> </ion-view>
```

I am trying to change the color of the title by using css and it keeps to be gray. What is the right way to do is?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to add to your CSS the following line:

```
.pane {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Could you give some code? also make sure that your CSS file is imported after the ionic CSS file.
    ```<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ionic.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pane` css class with `!important` to override the ion default background color,

```
   .pane {
        background-color: #464646!important;
    }
```

and for changing the font color use:

```
.bar.bar-stable .title{
    color:#FFF!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution is:

```
.frame_look_feel {
    background-color: #FD3583;
}
```

Adding your style.css after ionic.css

Answer (score -1):

The problem is of css specificity. Your css rule

```
.frame_look_feel {
    background-color: #FFFFFFF;
}
```

This rule has specificity 10. The ionic rules generally have higher specificity. That's why your style is not applied. Look [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more details.
Try something like

```
.frame_look_feel.custom_color {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to change just the text color :

```css
.frame_look_feel {
color: red;
}
```

of background as said by others

```css
.frame_look_feel {
background-color: red;
}
```